# Magento 2 checkout Shipping Prices missing

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, knockoutjs

I am trying to get the shipping price to display on my checkout.  It's accessed via knockout.js in the template Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html (this is the standard shipped with Magento)

```
  <td class="col col-price">
      <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
      <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- /ko -->
  </td>
```

I have two shipping methods set up - free and flat rate.  The method and carrier titles show but the price is missing.  See screen shot...

[image]

I haven't made any changes to the checkout_index_index.xml file.  For the flat rate shipping I have a price of 3.99.

Are there any suggestions how I can begin to investigate why this isn't working.  I'm completely new to knockoutjs and relatively new to Magento.  Thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem and have posted a solution here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131394/magento-2-new-checkout-step-shipping-method-prices-not-showing/131396#131396

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="shipping-methods" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Mike_Checkout/js/view/shipping-methods</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="price" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">price</item>
    </item>
</item>
```