# Magento 2: New Checkout step – Shipping Method prices not showing

Tags: magento2, module, checkout, template, knockoutjs

I would like to add a new Checkout step to the Checkout page but would like to place it **between** the customer's shipping details (name, address, email) and the shipping methods radio buttons. To do this, I have removed the Shipping Methods radio buttons (li#opc-shipping_method) from `shipping.html`and placed it in a custom module. Apart from removing the shipping methods, I haven't touched the shipping.html file.

```
#Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Address'" data-role="title"></div>
<div id="checkout-step-shipping"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <!-- ko if: (!quoteIsVirtual) -->
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

    <!-- Address form pop up -->
    <!-- ko if: (!isFormInline) -->
    <button type="button"
            data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
            class="action action-show-popup">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
        <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-form') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->

    <!-- Inline address form -->
    <!-- ko if: (isFormInline) -->
    <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Before adding my new step between the shipping details and the shipping methods, I enabled the new module containing the shipping methods to make sure all was okay. The shipping methods show on the checkout as exepcted, but the prices aren't being displayed!
[image]

My new module is made up of the following:

```
#Mike/Checkout/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mike_Checkout" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

---

```
#Mike/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-methods" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Mike_Checkout/js/view/shipping-methods</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array"></item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

```
#Mike/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-methods.js
(This is pretty much just a copy of Magento_Checkout/view/web/js/view/shipping.js to make sure I have all of methods I need)
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
],
function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Mike_Checkout/shipping-methods'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isFormInline: addressList().length == 0,

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'shipping_methods',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Shipping Methods',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                17
            );


            return this;
        },

        /**
        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
        * for switching to your custom step 
        */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
        * @returns void
        */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        },


        rates: shippingService.getShippingRates(),
        isLoading: shippingService.isLoading,

        /**
         * Set shipping information handler
         */
        setShippingInformation: function () {
            if (this.validateShippingInformation()) {
                setShippingInformationAction().done(
                    function () {
                        stepNavigator.next();
                    }
                );
            }
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        validateShippingInformation: function () {
            var shippingAddress,
                addressData,
                loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]',
                emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn();

            if (!quote.shippingMethod()) {
                this.errorValidationMessage('Please specify a shipping method.');

                return false;
            }

            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
            }

            if (this.isFormInline) {

                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');

                if (this.source.get('shippingAddress.custom_attributes')) {
                    this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.custom_attributes.data.validate');
                }

                if (this.source.get('params.invalid') ||
                    !quote.shippingMethod().method_code ||
                    !quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code ||
                    !emailValidationResult
                ) {
                    return false;
                }

                shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                addressData = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(
                    this.source.get('shippingAddress')
                );

                //Copy form data to quote shipping address object
                for (var field in addressData) {

                    if (addressData.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                        shippingAddress.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                        typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                        _.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])
                    ) {
                        shippingAddress[field] = addressData[field];
                    } else if (typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                        !_.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])) {
                        shippingAddress = addressData;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    shippingAddress.save_in_address_book = 1;
                }
                selectShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
            }

            if (!emailValidationResult) {
                $(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').focus();

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


    });
}
);
```

---

```
#Mike/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-methods.html

<li id="opc-shipping_method"
class="checkout-shipping-method"
data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
role="presentation">
<div class="checkout-shipping-method">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Methods'" data-role="title"></div>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-shipping-method-form') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content"
         role="tabpanel"
         aria-hidden="false">
        <!-- ko if: rates().length  -->
        <form class="form methods-shipping" id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="submit: setShippingInformation" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
                <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Method'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-price" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Method Title'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-carrier" data-bind="i18n: 'Carrier Title'"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <!--ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'}-->
                    <tr class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.selectShippingMethod">
                        <td class="col col-method">
                            <!-- ko ifnot: method.error_message -->
                            <!-- ko if: $parent.rates().length == 1 -->
                            <input class="radio"
                                   type="radio"
                                   data-bind="attr: {
                                                checked: $parent.rates().length == 1,
                                                'value' : method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code,
                                                'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                             }" />
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!--ko ifnot: ($parent.rates().length == 1)-->
                            <input type="radio"
                                   data-bind="
                                            value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                            checked: $parent.isSelected,
                                            attr: {
                                                'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                            },
                                            click: $parent.selectShippingMethod"
                                   class="radio"/>
                            <!--/ko-->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="col col-price">
                            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
                            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </td>

                        <td class="col col-method"
                                data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>

                        <td class="col col-carrier"
                                data-bind="text: method.carrier_title, attr: {'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- ko if:  method.error_message -->
                    <tr class="row row-error">
                        <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
                            <div class="message error">
                                <div data-bind="text: method.error_message"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="no-display">
                                <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code}"/>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <!-- /ko -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shippingAdditional') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <!-- ko if: errorValidationMessage().length > 0 -->
            <div class="message notice">
                <span><!-- ko text: errorValidationMessage()--><!-- /ko --></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: rates().length > 0 --><div class="no-quotes-block"><!-- ko i18n: 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'--><!-- /ko --></div><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

I have worked out that the template: `$parent.getRegion('price')` isn't being pulled in, in new `shipping-methods.html` file.

```
<td class="col col-price">
    <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</td>
```

I'm guessing my module isn't able to access the templates it needs to generate the prices?

Update:
I've noticed that `isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax` is set to `false` in the `window.checkoutConfig`, though, this is `true` on the M2 demo site checkout. Any relation?

Also, from further research, it looks like the shipping method prices are generated via the `Magento_Tax/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html` template. Why is this not available to my new module?

> To summarise:
>   The shipping method prices aren't showing in my new module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working! I needed to included the `Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price` component (and display area) as a child of my new step module in my checkout_index_index.xml:

```
#app/code/Mike/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

<item name="shipping-methods" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Mike_Checkout/js/view/shipping-methods</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="price" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">price</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: i am getting this error when trying to use your module - Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at UiClass.validateShippingInformation

Comment: THANK YOU @MikeMason  I'm working on essentially the same change as you and was baffled by this same bug.  Including this via XML solved my issue.  Thanks for the tip!